# BackAndroid not working properly in ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have used BackAndroid ,if moving from screen 1 -> screen 2 -> screen3 ,,
I am able to come back from Screen3 -> Screen 2 but unable come back using hardware button from Screen2 -> Screen1 in  android.

I need help on this question

Comment: Can you please share your code so we can check issue

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are resetting your navigation stack when navigating from screen 1 to screen 2. So your navigation stack starts from screen 2.

For example. 
When navigating from login page to home view, you may reset navigation stack so that when you are logged in and though you press back button you are not directed to login page.